# String detection on C

Tags: c, string

Been stuck on this for ages, cant figure why the the failsafe is not detecting the string.

```
char EmpCatString[10];
    printf("Choose Employee Category CTO or PM or PA");
    scanf_s("%9s", &EmpCatString, sizeof(EmpCatString)) == 1;
        printf("%s\n", EmpCatString);
        if (EmpCatString == "CTO" || EmpCatString == "PM" || EmpCatString == "PA")
        {
            state = 3;
        }
        else
            printf("please enter a valid Employee Category: \nCTO:\nPM\nPA\n=>");
```

Comment: this is explained at the beginning of string section in every C book. Please [find a good one and read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714)

Answer (score 2):

use `strcmp`. if the result is `0`, the strings are the same. `==` here is comparing the memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement

```
if (EmpCatString == "CTO" || EmpCatString == "PM" || EmpCatString == "PA")
```

What you are actually comparing are the addresses of `EmpCatString` and the address of the literal `”CTO”`.  Not the contents of the two strings.  You need to compare the values pointed to by `EmpCatString` and the values of the literal pointer `”CTO”`

Use one of the functions like `strcmp` to compare the values.